# Avoid UAC prompt

Tags: windows, manifest, uac

I've a app embeded with manifest `*.exe.manifest`. When I launch executable it shows UAC prompt every time. How can I avoid this? I have element `requireAdministrator` with attrubute `level` equal to `requireAdministrator`.  Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the UAC elevation prompt because you **asked** for it.  The operative word here is *require*.  If the user isn't currently running elevated then that's always going to invoke the elevation prompt.

If you don't want that to happen then you do have to replace `requireAdministrator` with `asInvoker`.  With the side-effect that your program won't run with the elevated privileges or course.  And no, you cannot elevate silently, that would defeat the point of UAC.  The point of UAC is not to stop you from doing something, it is to let the user know.